# Laravel 5.8 - execute background job from console command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

My project is based on Laravel 5.8.
I have a [console command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan) which perform some heavy tasks (generating very big PDF files, sending massive emails, etc.)

I tried to move these tasks to a background processes using [jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues).
Here is what I did in order to test how it works:

`php artisan make:job TestJob`

The job file:

```
class TestJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $data;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        sleep(5);
        $date = new \DateTime();
        $currentDateTime = $date->format('Ymd-His');
        $logFileName = "logs/testjob-$currentDateTime.log";
        $content = var_export($this->data, true);
        $res = Storage::disk('local')->put($logFileName, $content);
        echo "[TestJob] Print to log file: $logFileName\n";
    }
}
```

Console command file:

```
public function handle()
{
    echo "[Console Command] Starting...\n";

    $someData = [
        'First name' => 'John',
        'Surname' => 'Doe'
    ];
    TestJob::dispatch($someData);
    echo "[Console Command] Finished!\n";
}
```

On execution, this is the output:

```
[Console Command] Starting...
                                                                <<< delay 5 sec.   
[TestJob] Print to log file: logs/testjob-20210628-114321.log
[Console Command] Finished!
```

**The problem:**
The job is executed inside the script, and **not in background**.

What should I do to make it run in background?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your queue connection (driver) from sync to redis (or another supported queue driver). You can do it in your .env file (for example: QUEUE_CONNECTION=database).

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#driver-prerequisites